# Can't read from the source file or disk on RAID 1 drive

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I am getting the following error "Can't read from the source file or disk" when trying to copy a large file.  I get the same error no mater what other drive I try to copy it to (which makes sense as the error seem to be related to the source file or disk).   However the source file is on a RAID 1 protected drive, so I though this would not have been possible. A windows 8 error scan on the drive reveals no errors. Is there a way to recover the data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of the drive in RAID is failing, may be couple of bad sector,  s.m.a.r.t report of each drive will help to determine the condition of drives.

[since RAID 1](http://en.guiderecovery.com/data-decovery/raid-data-recovery/) is mirror only, try copying from single drive attaching to normal system instead of RAID.